# Cosa significa "patire" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Il signor Podestà*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> – … che lui non abbia nozione della sua colpa – ce l’ha, intendiamoci, ce l’ha a mucchio – e si ostini a negare, a difendersi finché voi due perdiate la testa. Non vorrei, insomma, finissimo in Tribunale. 
>         – Non finiamo laggiú, – disse Giovanni, – finisce tutto qui e regolare. **Patisce** al portafoglio, ma capirà anche lui che il portafoglio non butta sangue.

Potreste spiegarmi il senso di questo "patisce" che appare in questo brano? Ho cercato il verbo "patire" in alcuni dizionario, ma non ho saputo trovare nulla che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Comment: Credo sia nel senso che il portafoglio del personaggio farà le spese della situazione che si è creata, ovvero  soffrirà (per mancanza di denaro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una persona può patire ai reni, allo stomaco e così via, nel senso di soffrire. Nel caso specifico, la persona cui si riferisce Giovanni, patirà al portafoglio, considerato come una parte del corpo: "Gli farà male il portafoglio”.

Per qualcuno molto attaccato al denaro, una perdita finanziaria può essere più dolorosa che una martellata sul pollice.